# AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'to_csv' ---

Tags: python, pandas

I want to save my model output to csv but I get this error `AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'to_csv'`.

```
gf = df['findings'].astype(str)
preprocess_text = gf.str.strip().replace("\n","")
t5_prepared_Text = "summarize: "+preprocess_text
print ("original text preprocessed: \n", preprocess_text)

tokenized_text = tokenizer.encode(str(t5_prepared_Text), return_tensors="pt").to(device)


# summmarize 
summary_ids = model.generate(tokenized_text,
                                num_beams=4,
                                no_repeat_ngram_size=2,
                                min_length=30,
                                max_length=100,
                                early_stopping=True)

output = tokenizer.decode(summary_ids[0], skip_special_tokens=True)
print ("\n\nSummarized text: \n",output)
```

output

```
original text preprocessed: 
0       There is XXXX increased opacity within the rig... 
1       There is XXXX increased opacity within the rig...
2       There is XXXX increased opacity within the rig...
3       Interstitial markings are diffusely prominent ...
4       Interstitial markings are diffusely prominent ...
                          ...                        
4307    There is enlargement of the cardiac silhouette...
4308    There is enlargement of the cardiac silhouette...
4309                                                  nan
4310                                                  nan
4311    The heart is normal in size and contour. There...
Name: findings, Length: 4312, dtype: object


Summarized text: 
 the heart is normal in size and con... 4308. there is enlargement of the cardiac... nan 4310 - the dtype: object:
```

Saving to a dataframe

```
output.to_csv('/content/drive/MyDrive/hid.csv')
```

error

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-22-4812a4b978bb> in <module>
----> 1 output.to_csv('/content/drive/MyDrive/hid.csv')

AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'to_csv'
```

Comment: check the output of `type(output)`, is `tokenizer.decode` vectorized, or does it convert the Series to string?

Comment: `type(output)` prints `str`.

Comment: I think you have to apply your function to each item of the series, not on the Series directly.